# Mapping key value pairs between two JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, join

I have two JavaScript objects:

```
const widgetsObj = {
    inputWidget: "MyInputWidget", 
    checkboxWidget: "MyCheckboxWidget", 
    geoWidget: "MyGeoWidget"
};

 this.components = {
            "MyInputWidget": MyInputWidget, 
            "MyCheckboxWidget": MyCheckboxWidget, 
            "MyGeoWidget": MyGeoWidget
        };
```

The end goal is to map all keys from `widgetsObj` to all values from `this.components`. The end object should look like this.

```
let endObj = {
    inputWidget: MyInputWidget, 
    checkboxWidget: MyCheckboxWidget, 
    geoWidget: MyGeoWidget
}
```

Right now, I am doing this like so

```
let returnObj = {};
        for(const key of Object.keys(widgets)) {
            if(this.components.hasOwnProperty(widgets[key])) {
                returnObj[key] = this.components[widgets[key]];
            }
        }
        return returnObj;
```

where `widgets` represents `widgetsObj`.

Is there a better way to do this rather than look for each value by mapping through the whole object repeatedly?

Comment: I personally don't know, how to do it better. Maybe you can rethink your problem? Is there a way for you to have a single collection of widgets only, or components only, which already has this mapping preset correctly? Side note: I don't think `hasOwnProperty` is needed in this particular case.

Comment: The reason I am using hasOwnProperty is so that this.components which is a context object of a React class doesn't end up looking through its prototype chain, which might slow the whole thing down. 
Do you still think its not required?

Answer (score 2):

It might be a little cleaner to use `.reduce` instead of `for...of...` loop:

```
Object.keys(widgetsObj).reduce( (obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = this.components[widgetsObj[key]];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: This definitely looks a lot cleaner.
However, is there any runtime improvement that you are aware of by using either of those options?

Comment: No, `reduce` doesn't have significant runtime improvement than `for...of` loop. It is just more functional flavor. Comparing with your implementing, the only improvement is to get rid of `hasOwnProperty` check. But as the first comment mentioned, `hasOwnProperty` may not be needed in this case.

Comment: That does not work, you should be assigning to `widgetsObj`keys not its values. Should be `Object.keys(widgetsObj).reduce((obj, key) => (obj[key] = components[widgetsObj[key]], obj), {});`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Blindman67. I have updated the answer.